# Get appropriate properties for Entity Manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to create my custom configuration for `EntityManager`, however I want to set all properties suitable for it from `application.properties`.
Here I set properties `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` and `hibernate.dialect` explicitly. But I don't know which properties will be passed in `application.properties`. They can be changed from this file.
How to get all appropriate properties from `application.properties` for `EntityManager`.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {ENTITY_TO_SCAN});

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}
```

Comment: You are explicitly mentioning `application.properties` does this imply you are using Spring Boot?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I use spring boot

Comment: Then why create it yourself? Spring BOot already creates that and you can configure all of that just using properties. You are making things more complex than needed.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm implementing two different databases for one project. And I need customize it mannually. I can't avoid this(

Comment: To customize use a `BeanPostProcessor` or the special `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderCustomizer` to customize the builder. Nonetheless you can still use the auto-config classes (at least the builder) to bind automatically and create the entity manager. You don't have to through everything out of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your appropriate properties will be available in JpaProperties bean, if they are declared properly in application.properties file.

```
    @Autowired
    JpaProperties jpaProperties;
```

The jpa properties format should be like this.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

prefix `spring.jpa.properties.*`
Then you can update your entity manager bean like

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager(JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {ENTITY_TO_SCAN});

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties.getProperties());

    return em;
}
```